# null is not an object (evaluating 'n.IsAndroid')

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native

Trying to run react native, the build is running successfully but I get this error. I have deleted the build, installed Pods, re ran it. I've searched the net for this problem and this specific one does not show anywhere.

[image: Error]

Comment: Is there any 3rd party library you are using ?

Comment: @Kais im not entirely sure what that means

Comment: Solved it again you have to start your metro bundler before you start the emulator.